# What are the punishments of past acts of homosexuality done in ignorance? Is it obligatory to tell about it to my to be spouse?

Tags: punishment, homosexuality

It was about 2011, I was 14 years old my cousin told me about man and women private organs and one night he was sleeping with me in the room alone with lights off he woke me and take my hand on his penis and after that day we would spend weekends together, naked and doing acts. Now I realized I was doing wrong and have started leaving these thing and stopped meeting him because when I meet him my brain reminds me all those acts.

Is there any punishment for all those acts of ignorance in Islam?

Is it obligatory for me to tell this to the person I am getting married?

Comment: *Caveat:* If sodomy (penetration) did take place and you are sure about it, then make sure that you don't marry the the guy's sister, daughter etc. Because it's haram to marry them in that case.

Comment: @BleedingFingers Can you please clarify your statement with a hadith/verse/source?

Comment: @Seeker [2414](http://www.sistani.org/english/book/48/2348/).

Comment: @BleedingFingers Thanks for the link. That's just a scholar's understanding, which he didn't back with a relevant verse or hadtih.

Answer (score 7):

No, don't tell your would be spouse or to anyone for the Prophet has said,

> Every one of my followers will be forgiven except those who expose
>   (openly) their wrongdoings. An example of this is that of a man who
>   commits a sin at night which Allah has covered for him, and in the
>   morning, he would say (to people): "I committed such and such sin last
>   night,' while Allah had kept it a secret. During the night Allah has
>   covered it up but in the morning he tears up the cover provided by
>   Allah Himself. Bukhari and Muslim

Once you have asked God sincerely for forgiveness, it's as good as not having done the deed in the first place. You shouldn't let the guilt bother you - and why should you feel guilty when God has forgiven you?

> Q39:53: 
>   Say, "O My servants who have transgressed against themselves [by sinning], do not despair of the mercy of Allah . Indeed, Allah
>   forgives all sins. Indeed, it is He who is the Forgiving, the
>   Merciful."

This is also one of the reasons why the Prophet instructed us to separate the beds of children when they reach 10 years old. As a future parent, it's your duty to ensure your children don't go through the same experience as you did. Finally, if you discover your cousin is still in this acts, then you should ask him to desist. I know this is a very difficult thing to do, maybe you could get the message across to him through some other way, without doing it in person. God will make it easy, in sha Allah.

Answer (score 6):

There's no worldly punishment for acts done in ignorance.  By stopping the act and staying away from him is a very good sign Alhamdulillah.   What you should do is still make tawbah and astaghfir to Allah.

In Surah aali-Imran 3:135 Allah says =

> "And those who, when they commit an immorality or wrong themselves,
>   remember Allah and seek forgiveness for their sins - and who can
>   forgive sins except Allah ? - and do not persist in what they have
>   done while they know."

Allah is the Most Merciful and Forgiver.  There's no doubt if you make tawbah and astaghfir, Allah will erase your sins.

Now, you cannot speak about your sins to anyone.  Don't tell your future wife or anyone you know.  The sin is between you and Allah and should never be disclosed.  Once you repent you should do good deeds and stay away from these acts.

in Surah az-Zumar 39:53 =

> Say, "O My servants who have transgressed against themselves, do not
>   despair of the mercy of Allah . Indeed, Allah forgives all sins.
>   Indeed, it is He who is the Forgiving, the Merciful."

Juts live your life in obeying Allah and keep in mind this life is temporary.  We can die at anytime.  We don't want to die in sin.

Allaho Alim